# How are macro parameters with repeated hashes in front (e.g. ##1 or ###1) resolved?

Tags: macros

Lets say we have the following LaTeX

```
\newcommand{\macrohell}[1]{\newcommand{\nested}[#1]{##1}}
```

`\macrohell{1}` followed by `\nested{2}` outputs `2`, and I would think that it would be for the following reason: first the input to `\macrohell` is replaced in all `#1` params, so that `\macrohell{1}` turns into `\newcommand{\nested}[(1)]{#(1)}`, then this `newcommand` is evaluated as if you had written `\newcommand{\nested}[1]{#1}` directly, defining the command `nested`.

Then, `\nested{2}` is evaluated, which just renders its input `2`.

However, if I edit the command to look like this

```
\newcommand{\macrohell}[1]{\newcommand{\nested}[#1]{##1 ##2 ##3}}
```

I would expect to get an error based on the previous logic, as there would be too many parameters for the number of inputs allowed (1 in this case).

But it doesn't give me an error, instead

```
\nested{2}{3}{4}
```

renders as `2 3 4`.

So this made me think that perhaps `##n` means that we resolve that parameter with respect to the "nth level" and *not* that we first resolve `#n` in the top level, and then resolve `#(#n)` in the "second level". Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: Your reasoning is almost correct, except that when you use `\macrohell`, first all double hashes become a single hash (`##`-> `#`, as well as `####`-> `##`, and so on), and _then_ all single-hash+number is replaced by the argument (`#1`->`(1)`, and `###1`-> `##(1)`, but not `##1`->`#(1)`). And the second code raises an error (as it should)...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code

```
\newcommand{\macrohell}[1]{\newcommand{\nested}[#1]{##1}}
\macrohell{1}
```

does

```
\newcommand{\nested}[1]{#1}
```

That's so simple. In the body of a definition `#` requires to be followed either by a number (from 1 to 9) or by another `#`. In the first case, TeX will substitute `#`*i* with the *i*-th argument; in the second case it will just deliver a single `#`. It is exactly what happens in the case above: the first (and only) argument to `\macrohell` is `1`, so expansion delivers the replacement text in the form shown above.

In the second case, the result can be syntactically right or wrong, depending on the context; if you do

```
\newcommand{\foo}{##1}
```

you will get an error upon expansion of `\foo`, because generally `#1` is not legal unless found in the replacement text during a macro definition.

As a consequence, `###1` would be generally wrong, but there are contexts where this might appear:

```
\def\funny#1#2{\vbox{\halign{\hfil###1\hfil\cr#2\crcr}}}
```

is legal code. The following plain TeX file witnesses it:

```
\def\funny#1#2{\vtop{\halign{\hfil###1\hfil\cr#2\crcr}}}

1) \funny{:}{abc\cr defghi}
\qquad
2) \funny{\hfill}{abc\cr defghi}

\bye
```

but I'm a bit cheating: the first call will result in the following expansion

```
\vtop{\halign{\hfil#:\hfil\cr abc\cr defghi\crcr}}
```

and indeed this is legal, but `###1` is composed of two separate “objects”: first `##`, which will deliver `#` upon expansion, and `#1` that will deliver the first argument. The cheat is because `\halign` *wants* a single `#` to denote the variable part in an alignment template, preceded and followed by (optional) fixed parts.

---

Maybe this will add to confusion, but you can try

```
\newcommand{\hellofamacro}[2]{\def#1##1{#2}}

\hellofamacro{\foo}{--#1--}

\foo{x}
```

which will yield –x–.

What happens? The definition is stored according to the rules above; the call of `\hellofamacro` will result in

```
\def\foo#1{--#1--}
```

The trick is that TeX internally doubles `#` when it finds it in the argument to a *macro* and then reduces `##` to `#` when, during expansion, it delivers tokens absorbed earlier.

Comment: The `tokcycle` package also uses the triple, as in `\def\whennotprocessingparameter#1#2{\tctestifcon\if@argnext{\@argnextfalse\cytoks\expandafter{\the\cytoks###1}}{\tctestifcon\ifcatSIX{\@argnexttrue}{#2}}}`