# Macro without arguments to define macro with arguments

Tags: macros, xparse, package-writing, optional-arguments, arguments

I'm trying to use `xparse` and generic TeX/LaTeX commands to write a macro (that takes no arguments) to define another macro that does take arguments:

```latex
\documentclass{minimal}
\RequirePackage{xparse,fmtcount}

\newcounter{mycounter}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mycounterHex}{O{1}}{}

\providecommand{\enableCounterCommands}{
    \RenewDocumentCommand{\mycounterHex}{O{1}}{\padzeroes[#1]{\hexadecimal{mycounter}}}
}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

When I compile this document with `pdflatex --interaction=nonstopmode`, I get the following error message:

```text
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \enableCounterCommands.
<to be read again> 
                   1
l.11 }
```

I believe that the problem is that TeX thinks I'm trying to refer to the (nonexistent) first argument of `\enableCounterCommands`, but I'm actually trying to reference the optional-with-default-value first argument of `\mycounterHex`. **How can I indicate to TeX that I am referencing the argument of `\mycounterHex`?**

Comment: Have you tried to double `#`? `...\padzeroes[##1]...`

Comment: related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/527577 https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42463

Comment: The double `#` seems to work well. Do you know if `xparse`'s `\RenewDocumentCommand` can be used to make a global redefinition from inside of another macro definition?

Answer (score 1):

You want `##1` in the replacement text.

On the other hand I don't see why defining `\mycounterHex` that way, when it's not difficult to have an expandable version using *any* counter.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\paddedhex}{O{0}m}
 {% #1 = size to pad with zeros to, #2 = counter name
  \zelnick_paddedhex:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \zelnick_paddedhex:nn
 {
  \int_compare:nT { #1-\str_count:e { \int_to_Hex:n { \value{#2} } } > 0 }
   {% we want to pad
    \prg_replicate:nn { #1-\str_count:e { \int_to_Hex:n { \value{#2} } } } { 0 }
   }
  \int_to_Hex:n { \value{#2} }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcounter{mycounter}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{mycounter}{42}

\paddedhex{mycounter}

\paddedhex[4]{mycounter}

\setcounter{mycounter}{1234567}

\paddedhex{mycounter}

\paddedhex[4]{mycounter}

\paddedhex[8]{mycounter}

\edef\temp{\paddedhex[8]{mycounter}}

\texttt{\meaning\temp}% show full expandability

\end{document}
```

We first convert the counter's value to hexadecimal, count the number of characters and, if it's less than the stated size to pad to, we add the required number of zeros.

[image]

Full expandability means that you can for instance say

```
\renewcommand{\themycounter}{\paddedhex[4]{mycounter}}
```

You could have your section numbers in hexadecimal padded to four digits with

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\paddedhex[4]{section}}
```

and this would work with `\label` and `\ref`.

You wouldn't be able to with `fmtcount` facilities.